# Struct is getting wrong size

Tags: c#, struct

I am now trying to get the Struct size of C #.
However, the size of the struct shown below is 16 bytes. It is normal that 58byte should come out, but I do not know what is wrong.

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack =1)]
public struct LOBBY_USER_INFO 
{
    LOBBY_DATA_HEADER ldh;
    int userPixNumber; //4byte
    byte[] userID; //50byte

    public LOBBY_USER_INFO(int data_size, int userPixNumber, string userID) 
    {

        this.ldh.data_size = data_size;
        this.userID = new byte[50];
        this.userID = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userID);
        this.userPixNumber = userPixNumber;
    }
}

int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LOBBY_USER_INFO));
```

Comment: What is `LOBBY_DATA_HEADER`, please?

Comment: The field userID is a reference type and thas it has the size of a pointer in the struct. Take a look at the 'fixed' keyword and fixed buffers

Comment: byte[] userID; //50byte This isn't true. userID is just a pointer.

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko's Source
[MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 50)]
Has been resolved in the form of.

Thank you all.

Comment: @J.Kim, not related to the question, but important to note: the way you're initializing `userID` is rather dangerous. The `userID` not guaranteed to be 50 bytes long at all. The `this.userID = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userID);` assignment will replace the array created in the previous line with a new array which length depends on `userID` parameter string length. More safe implementation would be: `var userBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userID); Array.Copy(userBytes, this.userID, Math.Min(this.userID.Length, userBytes.Length));`

Comment: Wow!! Thanks to you, I know what's good.

Answer (score 3):

`byte[]` is a *class* not a *struct*, so `sizeof(byte[])` is the size of **reference** (pointer) which is `4` or `8` bytes (`32` or `64` bits)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Dmitry Bychenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42779757/4295017):

If you want the `userID` array to be marshaled within the structure, use `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ...)` attribute:

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct LOBBY_USER_INFO
{
    //LOBBY_DATA_HEADER ldh;
    int userPixNumber; //4byte
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 50)]
    byte[] userID; //50byte
}

// .................
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LOBBY_USER_INFO));
// size is 54 now
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Thanks to you, it is output in 58 byte.

Thank you all for your support.